# Cannot access Oracle APEX through localhost after installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

As the title says, I cannot access APEX on localhost. The page is asking me for a username and password. I have followed the steps in this page: https://www.foxinfotech.in/2019/04/install-oracle-apex-19-1-in-eleven-easy-steps.html and I also made sure that APEX is already installed by running this query:  SELECT STATUS FROM DBA_REGISTRY WHERE COMP_ID = 'APEX'.
I also tried using different port numbers by using dbms_xdb.sethttpport. I also made sure that it is the port being listened to through LSNRCTL STATUS. I also made sure that the ports that I was using are not used by other applications.

I don't know what else is causing this problem and I can't see anything online. Please help if you've already encountered this problem. Hints or suggestions that may lead me to the right solution are also welcome.

**Update**
Here's the screenshot of the prompt that asks me for username and password:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q98KC.png)

Comment: What is the username/password screen. Could you share a screenshot ?